logo image not showing when resizing screen
I need my logo image to always be on top of the screen, always 80px from the top and center of the page.
When I decrease screen height the logo image gets cut and does not show
How can I solve this?
I tried using position: absolute but then the logo overlaps with the content so I don't think that's how you do it.

my SignUpStyles.js
import styled from "styled-components";

export const StyledContainer = styled.div`
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 0 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
`;

export const LogoWrap = styled.div`
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

`;
...


my SignUp.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyledContainer, LogoWrap, Input, SignUpButton, SignUpType, NextButton, CurrentSignUpType } from "./styles/SignUpStyles.js";
import logo from "@assets/images/logo_big.svg";

function SignUp() {
  const [currentSignUpType, setCurrentSignUpType] = useState(null);
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);

  const signUpType = [
    { name: "signup as seller", type: "seller" },
    { name: "signup as user", type: "user" }
  ];

  const handleSignUpTypeChange = (type) => {
    setCurrentSignUpType(type);
    setShowForm(true);
  };

  const renderForm = () => {
   ...
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <StyledContainer>
        <div>
          <LogoWrap>
            <img src={logo} />
          </LogoWrap>
        </div>
        
...

        <div>
          <CurrentSignUpType>
       ...
          </CurrentSignUpType>
        </div>
        {showForm && (
          <form>
            <div>
              {renderForm()}
            </div>
            <SignUpButton>signup</SignUpButton>
          </form>
        )}
      </StyledContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SignUp;


The cause of the problem is the StyledContainer element is positioned absolutely. This means everything currently in your document (StyledContainer) is just floating on the body, that should not be the case. You should have centered the StyledContainer element differently. I would have added display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;
justify-content: center to the container of the StyledContainer element to make it center to the body and leave everything as it is, no need to change any other thing. This will result in the result you are expecting with the best practice.
Steps needed in your code:

Remove the position absolute and its related styles from StyledContainer
Add the flex center styling to the container of the StyledContainer element to center it on the screen

Secondly, If you don't want to remove the absolute positioning you could achieve this by changing the min-height to a number value e.g. 520px on the StyledContainer element.
